# ColdFusion 10 / Fusebox Hangs, Locks Server

Tags: java, tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, fusebox

We have a legacy application written several years ago that seems to be locking up our server.  Using VisualVM and FusionReaction (on a trial) we have narrowed it down to this particular application built with Fusebox.  However, it isn't a particular action within the application that seems to trigger the hang, but rather any action, at random, after a period of time has elapsed.  For some reason, after this thread locks up, all of the other threads seem to stack up behind it very quickly, waiting on something, and the whole server grinds to a halt very shortly.

I've got Fusion Reactor running, but it can't help (there are no slow queries or locks).  I've got VisualVM which can at least give me the following thread dump from the locked thread.  What is my next step?  I found some documentation that indicated it may have been a bug in the JVM, but I went from 1.6 (came with CF) to 1.7.0_65 (Ubuntu apt-get) and it didn't fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
"catalina-exec-3" - Thread t@176
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at coldfusion.compiler.ClassReader.skipFully(ClassReader.java:79)
    at coldfusion.compiler.ClassReader.skipAttrs(ClassReader.java:274)
    at coldfusion.compiler.ClassReader.skipMethods(ClassReader.java:284)
    at coldfusion.compiler.ClassReader.getSourceModTime(ClassReader.java:196)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache$1.fetch(TemplateClassLoader.java:421)
    at coldfusion.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:180)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache.fetchSerial(TemplateClassLoader.java:362)
    at coldfusion.util.AbstractCache.fetch(AbstractCache.java:58)
    at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get_statsOff(SoftCache.java:133)
    at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get(SoftCache.java:81)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.findClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:609)
    at coldfusion.runtime.RuntimeServiceImpl.getFile(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:828)
    at coldfusion.runtime.RuntimeServiceImpl.resolveTemplatePath(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:809)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:356)
    at cffusebox402eruntime2ecfmx2ecfm73232117.runPage(/path/to/our/application/fusebox40.runtime.cfmx.cfm:203)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2799)
    at cfindex2ecfm2109747722.runPage(/path/to/our/application/index.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:444)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:449)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:472)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:312)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:192)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:507)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:53)
    at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    - locked <20d21902> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <2b4f2aba> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Comment: If this is a ColdFusion issue then you need to inspect the ColdFusion logs and see what messages are being written to them. You can find the location of the logs in the ColdFusion administrator - [Log Files page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fd9)

Comment: Nothing is written to the logs.  The server acts normally until it hangs.  No errors, no "long requests," nothing.

Comment: Hmm that is odd. Typically when there are memory issues, timeout issues, errors, etc. something is written to the logs. ColdFusion may be a red herring here and just a victim of some other server issue. Not sure where to go from here...